# Parse date/time string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I have a log file from some system, the date/time format used `8/Sep/2016:08:21:32 -0500`.

How can I convert it into Excel recognized date/time value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the first `:` between the date and the time:

If you do not care about the time zone adjustment then this simple formula will work:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,":"," ",1)
```

Then format it in the date/time format you want as it will return a number that needs to be formatted properly.

[image]

To deal with time zone adjustment on the end use this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,":"," ",1)+RIGHT(A1,5)/100/24
```

[image]

Comment: What is the 2 `-` before substitute function for? Mine Excel 2013 does not seem to like them.

Comment: I am working in 2013.  It is just a way to change a text string to a value.  It is not the `--` that is the problem.  You data must be different than you posted.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with mine, check the screen http://i68.tinypic.com/105ebrm.png

Comment: It should work. Depending on your local setup you may need to use `;` instead of `,` to delineate between the criteria.